# Advice on how to handle Internationalization when there is a Database in the middle of the way

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

My site allows user to choose the language. All texts shown in the website are handled by the `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource` of Spring, that reads texts from some properties files.

I have a menu with many links, taken from a database.

My question is: where should I write the different languages for the text of the links? What's the best practice?

**1) Write all the languages inside the dabatase? For example this way?**

```
--------------------------------------------------
| id_link |   url  | italian | english | spanish |
--------------------------------------------------
| 1       |  /url  | Ciao    | Hello   | Hola    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**2) Bind dabatase and properties file? For example this way?**

```
---------------------------------
| id_link |   url  | description| 
--------------------------------
| 1       |  /url  | link1      |
---------------------------------
                          |              __ language_it.properties
                          |             |   link1= ciao
                          |             |
                          |-------------|__ language_en.properties
                                        |   link1= hello
                                        |
                                        |__ language_es.properties
                                            link1= hola
```

Comment: There is no best practice other than "choose what works in your specific situation". Both approaches have their benefits and their downsides and the downsides of one may start to outweigh the benefits depending on how large the application is, how many texts you have and how flexible you need to be in adding support for new languages for example.

Comment: 2nd that. I went with Solution 1 for our app. Faster and easier to maintain, but less flexible. Depends if you are planning to add dozens of languages in the near future?

Comment: Yes, I'm planning to add many other languages. I think I'll pick the solution n.2. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the second approach, where you store the key in the database and the i18n key in the properties.

This will allow to add more languages in the future, without chaning the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

One should be careful to underestimate database power, as doing everything on the java side seems so immediate. With an embedded DB maybe, read/only, O/R mapping holding everything in a bean it would be fast too.

However maintenance is more problematic. One may version properties in a real VCS. Use different translation agencies / other national branches of the firm.

Normally important, the properties should be maintained: commented on linguistic ambiguities.
Sorting texts, the possibility of having a glossary for consistent translation of terms.
A file in text format is easiest.

With properties one should still do some support for translating: by default the encoding is ISO-8859-1 which is insufficient for even English (comma like quotes). Small scripts for checking integrity, comparison to other languages and such are definitely needed.